# Ocultar y sumar datos con HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Buen día comunidad, pido su ayuda para este problema.

Tengo un archivo con 60 columnas y varias lineas, de ese archivo solo necesito tres columnas (Región, Evento y precio).

Hice un programa para enlistar esas tres columnas ordenando los datos por región, este es el código:

```
            s = new Scanner(fichero);
            String[] x = null;
            String[] salida = null;
            List<String[]> datos = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            String linea = "";
            double suma=0.0;
            int cambio=0;

            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                linea = s.nextLine(); 
                datos.add(linea.split("\\|"));
            }

            for (int h = 1; h<=9; h++){
                suma =0;
                for(int j=1; j<datos.size();j++){
                    x = datos.get(j);
                    cambio=Integer.parseInt(x[5]);
                    if(cambio == h){
                        System.out.print(x[5] + " | "+ x[15] + "   |   "+ x[29] + "\n");
                        suma += Double.parseDouble(x[29]);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("La suma de los eventos de la región " + h + " son: " + suma );  
                System.out.print("\n --------------------------------------------------------- \n");
            }
```

la salida que se genera tiene el siguiente formato:

Region   |   Evento   |   Precio

1      |    Evento 1   |  5.0

1      |    Evento 2   |  5.0

3      |    Evento 1   |  6.0

3      |    Evento 1   |  7.0

5      |    Evento 4   |  2.0

6      |    Evento 5   |  5.0

Lo que necesito es eliminar los eventos que se repiten por región y sumar los precios, por ejemplo, en región 3 hay dos eventos con el mismo nombre, se debe de mostrar solo un evento pero con el precio de los dos (13.0).

(Salida deseada)

Region   |   Evento   |   Precio

1      |    Evento 1   |  5.0

1      |    Evento 2   |  5.0

3      |    Evento 1   |  13.0

5      |    Evento 4   |  2.0

6      |    Evento 5   |  5.0

Lo estoy tratando de hacer con HashMap pero el me confundo porque en los ejemplos que encuentro tienen valores ya definidos, en mi caso son diferentes tipos de eventos.

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería enormemente.

Gracias por leer mi problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo diría que puedes usar un map por región y dentro tener los eventos. Y cada evento que tenga su precio y nombre. Primero la clase Evento:

```
public class Evento {

    private String name;
    private double price;

    public Evento(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void addPrice(double newPrice) {
        this.price += newPrice;
    }

}
```

Fíjate que tiene un método de añadir precio.

Ahora modifico un poco tu código:

```
// ya se ha leido el fichero y está en a variable x
Map<Integer, Evento> regiones = new HashMap<>();
for (int h = 1; h <= 9; h++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < datos.size(); j++) {
        x = datos.get(j);
        // la region
        Integer region = Integer.parseInt(x[5]);
        // el evento
        Evento evento = new Evento(x[15]);
        if (regiones.containsKey(region)) {
            // si ya tenemos un evento en el map - lo sacamos de ahí
            evento = regiones.get(region);
        }
        // añadir el precio
        evento.addPrice(Double.parseDouble(x[29]));
        regiones.put(region, evento);
    }
}
```

Falta mostrarlos:

```
for (Integer region : regiones.keySet()) {
    Evento evento = regiones.get(region);
     System.out.print(region + " | " + evento.getName() + " | " + evento.getPrice() + "\n");
}
```

Mas o menos es esto. A ver si te sirve.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, lo estoy checando y me salía un error en "Evento evento = new.." tuve que hacer la clase evento static y dejó de marcar error, pero a la hora de ejecutar me sale " mensaje: null" ¿Alguna idea del por qué?

Comment: Muestra todo tu código y donde se produce el error

Comment: Puse el código como respuesta a mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Ejemplo { 

    private String name;
    private Double price;

    public  Ejemplo(String name){
        this.setName(name);
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public void addPrice(double newPrice){
        this.price +=newPrice;
    }

    /*public static class Evento{

        private String name;
        private Double price;

        public  Ejemplo(String name){
            this.setName(name);
        }
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public double getPrice(){
            return price;
        }
        public void addPrice(double newPrice){
            this.price +=newPrice;
        }

    }*/
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        File fichero = new File("/home/testUser/det_llam_gsm_COMPRA_SUSCRIPCIONES_20190713_235959_zte.unl");
        Scanner s = null;
        //String[] x = null;
        try {
        s = new Scanner(fichero);
                String[] x = null;
                String[] salida = null;
                List<String[]> datos = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                String linea = "";

                while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                    linea = s.nextLine(); 
                    datos.add(linea.split("\\|"));
                }//fin while

                //*********************************Parte Implementada*********************************************
                Map<Integer, Ejemplo> regiones = new HashMap<>();

                for (int h = 1; h<9; h++){
                    for(int j=1; j<datos.size();j++){
                        x = datos.get(j);
                        Integer region = Integer.parseInt(x[5]);
                        Ejemplo evento = new Ejemplo (x[15]);
                        if (regiones.containsKey(region)){
                            evento = regiones.get(region);
                        }
                        evento.addPrice(Double.parseDouble(x[29]));
                        regiones.put(region, evento);
                    }//fin for j
                }


                //imprimir salida
                for(Integer region : regiones.keySet()){
                    Ejemplo evento = regiones.get(region);
                    System.out.println(region + "  |  " + evento.getName() + "  |  " + evento.getPrice());
                }
                //********************************Fin Parte Implementada**********************************************        
        }//Fin try
        catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Mensaje: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
        if (s != null)
        s.close();
            } catch (Exception ex2) {
                System.out.println("Mensaje 2: " + ex2.getMessage());
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Error:    Mensaje: null

lo que eh notado es que no entra a la condición "if (regiones.containsKey(region))"